# Operating systems vs. database management systems

Tags: database, operating-system

Context: I'm a student who just finished an operating systems course and is currently taking a databases course.

I'm confused about how the OS and the DBMS interact with one another.

For example, what happens when a user program tries to access a file? Does a system call get invoked that is then handled by the OS to find the correct file and data? Or is the call handled by the DBMS, which can then more efficiently find the data (tuple/record) using a B+ tree for example? And then the DBMS makes a call to the OS to actually get the data?

Is the database only accessed if using a programming language like SQL? If I just write a simple C program that writes a file to disk, is the data really stored in a "database" or just in some block on disk where the information for the file is stored within the inode for that file?

I apologize if this isn't the correct forum to ask this question and also if this question is too simple. I tried looking online, but surprisingly didn't find much info (maybe I was searching for the wrong key words?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, what happens when a user program tries to access a file? 
That depends on how the user program is accessing the file. fopen/read/write calls are offered by the filesystem managed by the OS.

Does a system call get invoked that is then handled by the OS to find the correct file and data? 
If a database is used, the database manages it's own set of data files, and indexes into those data files. The database engine executes IO requests which are handled by the underlying OS. Additionally, the database most possibly will also do caching to reduce file IO.

Or is the call handled by the DBMS, which can then more efficiently find the data (tuple/record) using a B+ tree for example? And then the DBMS makes a call to the OS to actually get the data?
Depending on the database query, the data can be read sequentially, or accessed randomly via an index lookup.

Is the database only accessed if using a programming language like SQL? If I just write a simple C program that writes a file to disk, is the data really stored in a "database" or just in some block on disk where the information for the file is stored within the inode for that file?
It's stored in the filesystem that might used a block based design. A simple C program should use an SDK to connect to a database, and then invoke SQL statements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If DBMS has security-related features, shouldn't it not be accessible with native C?

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends upon the operating system and the database system.Industrial-strength operating systems have support for multiple file structures and record level locking. A database system can make use of the facilities provide by the operating system for locking and indices. In that case, much of the database works by invoking system service calls to the operating system.

With the rise of brain damaged operating systems that do not support records at all, let alone record or column locking, database system does nearly of the work, beyond low level  I/O calls. Some operating systems are so brain damaged that database systems have to create their own partitions and effectively manage their own file systems within the partition. There are no files at all from the perspective of the operating system.

Comment: @user334403 can you provide example of such "_brain damaged operating system_"?